# Modify Liferay's Marketplace portlet

Tags: java, plugins, liferay

I have installed an application for Social Networking from Liferay's Marketplace in my portal. It includes a portlet with a wall (similar to Facebook's one). I would like to introduce a slight modification to this portlet. I know I can modify the JSP directly in the server's web apps deployment folder, but that doesn't seem like the right choice in terms of maintainability. I have also thought about using a hook but, as far as I know, they can only be applied to Liferay core plugins, since add-on's are deployed as separate web apps.

Any idea on what I could do? I am new to Liferay, so maybe there's some simple solution I have overlooked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifery allows extending a plugin using another plugin.Please refer this link for details.

http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en